# Python - solving basic noisy captcha

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, captcha, python-tesseract

I am trying to solve basic captchas that have a little bit of noise but it is proving to be difficult.

This is a sample image of one of the captchas:

[image: sample.png]

This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("sample.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

The output that I get using this code is: `"_JHB9TPR`

This is obviously not correct. I think more work needs to be done with making the image clearer so that the letters stick out, but it doesn't help that the letters are the same colours as some of the background noise so that leads it to incorrectly recognise some letters.

Is there any other technique (with sample code) that I should be doing?

Comment: I think you are in the right direction with the thresholding. Altough, I doubt that `pytesseract` can handle angled text, I might be wrong.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70100889/8658598) answer should be helpful for your specific question. Could you confirm that `pytesseract` can extract angled text by generating same text manually without any noise?

Comment: @doneforaiur Well it is able to get some of the letters right. I think the problem is that it struggles with certain letters when the background noise blends in

Comment: this is a CAPTCHA. it's supposed to keep humans out that try to automate their way around the CAPTCHA. I believe it would defeat the purpose of this security measure to give you a solution. -- I think thresholding is wrong here. OCR does that on its own, ***if*** it requires that. modern OCR hates thresholded input and works better on raw input. humans usually don't know what filtering to apply and just destroy the information (thresholding is one such popular destroyer of information). you may want to try a median filter. if you put it in the wrong position of the pipeline, you will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific sample:

```
img = cv2.imread("./sample.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), sigmaX=1, sigmaY=1)


kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

txt = image_to_string(morph)
print(txt)
```

Outputs:

> JH69TPR

Which performs OCR on this image;

[image]

Edit; as Christoph Rackwitz suggested in the comments, I removed thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

This is two passes of 3x3 median filter followed by histogram stretching, then Otsu.

[image]

This is a ***CAPTCHA***. It is a security measure. If you can circumvent it on your own, you earned it. I have nothing to gain from circumventing it.

Any issues your OCR may have can be remedied with more training. If your OCR can't take training, it may be too old and you should look for something with more intelligence. Actual AI-based OCR could just be trained to tolerate the noise in such inputs. Anything based on last-century technology, even with AI "bolted on", will always struggle. Any OCR that needs thresholding or does its own thresholding is defective.